# Is this XSD incorrect (official XMPP specification)

Tags: xml, xsd, xmpp

Here:
http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0009.html#schema

in the middle of the schema, an element seems to be defined twice:

```
<xs:complexType> 
<xs:sequence> 
<xs:element name="member" type="MemberType">
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="member" type="MemberType">
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
```

Am I just a total XSD newbie or is this really incorrect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. This just requires two `<member>` nodes in sequence:

```
<...>
    <member>...</member>
    <member>...</member>
</...>
```

Comment: I thought this should be defined as <xs:sequence> 
<xs:element name="member" type="MemberType" minOccurs=2 maxOccurs=2></xs:sequence> -- but well, this means something different.

Comment: Thanks. I should have just tried to validate the schema against http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd.